# Is there any negative issue if we use `overflow:hidden` to clear float?

Tags: css, xhtml

Is there any negative issue if we use `overflow:hidden` to clear float. is it cross browser compatible IE 6, 7 , firefox , safai etc.?

Is `overflow:hidden` enough or we need to add `Zoom:1` too to make compatible with IE?

Is this way better than .clearfix to get cross browser compatibility?

Comment: I've never liked `overflow:hidden` because it's not really how the spec intended `overflow` to be used. Maybe I'm just not practical enough.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's not IE 6 compatible, so if you require support for that browser it's off the table.

Comment: @jtbandes then method would you prefer?

Comment: it has worked fine for me across most browsers.

Comment: I always use a clearfix like this: .clearfix { overflow: hidden; width: 100%; } and it works crossbrowser, never had a problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty comprehensive list of float clearing techniques here:

[How do you keep parents of floated elements from collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)

I personally use the "float the parent" technique exclusively.  It works in all commonly found browsers (IE6+, Firefox, Safari, etc.....), and it seems the "least dirty" of all the possible techniques.

**Edit for comment**:

This should work if I'm understanding you correctly:

```
#main {
     width: 900px;
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -450px;
}

#col1, #col2, #col3 {
     float: left;
     width: 300px;
}

<body>
     <div id="main">
          <div id="col1"></div>
          <div id="col2"></div>
          <div id="col3"></div>
     </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can u give me example on how to create 3 col fixed width centered layout with "float the parent" method

Comment: i didn't understood this part of #main {position: absolute;left:50%;  margin-left: -450px;}

Comment: That would center the layout.

Comment: u mean {margin:0 auto} will not work if we use "Float the parent" method  to build site

Comment: and is this all browser compatible including IE6