# CSS div to stretch with content which is positioned absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im having a few difficulties making a parent **div** stretch with its content which is positioned absolute.

The footer ends up at the bottom of the screen but not bottom of the document, which is obviously cause by the absolutes breaking the flow of the page.

[image: ht]

Im just wondering whether theres a way around this or a little hack to get things back in flow but keeping the absolute positioning.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697578/html-how-to-make-a-parent-div-grow-with-its-children

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can do this by floating the children

Comment: Parent will grow along with the children even when parent is positioned absolute . see this http://codepen.io/VamsiKaja/pen/RPqMNr

Comment: add more info to your question or add a codepen of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use javascript / jquery

```
$("#parent-div").height($("#footer").offset().top + $("#footer").height() )
```