# How can I make my DIV fully enclose floating DIV's inside it?

Tags: css

I am having a problem with my CSS. I have an area on my screen where there
are buttons. The number of buttons is variable. These buttons are enclosed 
inside of a DIV (sbr_btn). Something like this:

```
Outer DIV Outer DIV Outer DIV

 01  02  03  04  05
 06  07  08  ...
 71  72  73  74  75

Outer DIV Outer DIV Outer DIV
```

The problem is that because my buttons have float: left then the outer DIV 
does not enclose the buttons. It just ignores the height of all the buttons
and does not look like above. Is there some way that I can make the outer
DIV enclose the floating buttons?

```
<div id="sbr_btn" >
        <div><a href='xx'>01</a></div>
        <div><a href='xx'>02</a></div>
        <div><a href='xx'>03</a></div>
        <div><a href='xx'>04</a></div>
        <div><a href='xx'>05</a></div>
        <div><a href='xx'>06</a></div>
        many more
        <div><a href='xx'>75</a></div>
</div>


#sbr_btn div {
    float: left;
    padding: 4px;
    text-align: center;
}
#sbr_btn div a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1px 4px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    color: #111111;
}
```

Comment: Informative previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `overflow:hidden` on the containing `div`:

```
#sbr_btn {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VNp5k/1/).

Answer (score 2):

You could put an empty `<div>` at the end of the container with the `clear: both;` CSS style.  I include one after my floated elements to force their container to enclose them.

```
<div id="sbr_btn" >
    <div><a href='xx'>01</a></div>
    <div><a href='xx'>02</a></div>
    <div><a href='xx'>03</a></div>
    <div><a href='xx'>04</a></div>
    <div><a href='xx'>05</a></div>
    <div><a href='xx'>06</a></div>
    <!-- many more -->
    <div><a href='xx'>75</a></div>

    <div class="clearFix"></div>
</div>
```

```
.clearFix { clear: both; }
```

Also, simply setting the size of the container avoids the need for this solution.