# Why removing the overflow property changes the background color in this example?

Tags: css

I am experimenting with this tutorial [codeplay simple navigation with hover](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/make-a-simple-navigation-with-hover-transitions).I am not able to understand why removing the `overflow: hidden;` property from the `.navigation` class in this tutorial changes the background color? Isn't this property concerned with the decision of giving a scroll bar to the user or not in case the text in the box overflows.

Comment: It doesn't change the `background-color`. If floated elements have non-floated parent elements, then the parent will collapse. Check out [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218760/681807) and this [Clearing Floats article](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) for more information and other solutions for fixing this collapse

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `li` elements are floated. Setting an `overflow` other than `visible` on a wrapper of floated elements causes that wrapper to truly "wrap" the elements (otherwise, it does not recognize them and its height becomes zero).

The `overflow` allows one to not use a `clearfix` or some other means of getting the wrapper to wrap the float. *If you wanted to set the `overflow` to `visible` then a `clearfix` of some type would be needed to get the `.navigation` to gain height and wrap the `li` elements within it.