# jquery.height() and float parameter in CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'd noticed a strange behaviour of `jquery.height()` function. Have a look at the following code.

CSS:

```
div.text-field {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 3px;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="someid">
  <div class="text-holder">
    <div class="text-field">text here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
console.log($("someid").find("text-holder").height());
```

The last line outputs `0` if I have `float: left;` in CSS file, and otputs real height if I remove `float: left;`. What is the reason of such a behaviour? Can I use `height()` function together with `float: left;`?

Comment: Try to `clear` after float.

Comment: because `floats` remove the element from the normal flow. try using `overflow:hidden`

Comment: You should see [this][1]! Your question will completely answer there!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing

Comment: Just to give a direct solution/ hack to fetching the correct height in javascript for an unfloated parent with floated descendants: set parent as floated in javascript, get height (A), unset parent as floated, get height (B), The actual height = `max(A, B)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `float` elements are within a container, that element does not apply the height of the container, because the element is no longer in the "flow". It is removed from the current element, and applied to it's parent, hence the issue. You can fix it by using either `inline-block`, or `clear: both`

Answer (score 3):

I usually use a 0 height element with clear both as the last child in the container. This causes the container to "stretch" around the floating objects:

```
<div style="clear: both; line-height: 0; height: 0;">&nbsp;</div>
```

This is a variant on the [QuirksMode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html), and has good cross browser compatibility.

I've rewritten your code to include it and demonstrate the results:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>test</title>
<style type="text/css">
div.text-field
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 3px;
    float: left;
}

div.text-holder
{
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#output1").text($("#someid1 .text-holder").height());
    $("#output2").text($("#someid2 .text-holder").height());
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="someid1">
  <div class="text-holder">
    <div class="text-field">text here</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="output1">&nbsp;</div>

<br><br><br>

<div id="someid2">
  <div class="text-holder">
    <div class="text-field">text here</div>
    <div style="clear: both; line-height: 0; height: 0;">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="output2">&nbsp;</div>

</body>

</html>
```

The demonstration can also be viewed on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QBZMt/).

Answer (score 2):

because `floats` remove the element from the normal flow. try using `overflow:hidden`

see the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/iyizag/1/edit)**

for more details http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Answer (score 2):

`floats` removes element from the space therefore it occupies 0 space. So `height()` is space it takes up that is 0

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery the test script looks like:

```
console.log($("#someid").find(".text-holder").height());
```

if you modify the html to clear the float, the parent will gain height:

```
    <div id="someid">
        <div class="text-holder">
            <div class="text-field">text here</div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where I was using `float` for better element positioning. If however you (like me) know beforehand what the exact contents of the element will be, you can add a `height` attribute with a value (e.g. `height: 30px`) to your CSS class, so the jQuery `.height()` method does work.