# Margin Collapsing in Firefox Only

Tags: css, margin

I'm using this css on an html5 document and #pane is rendering in firefox with about a 30px margin at the top, while on ie and chrome it is flush at the top.  What am I missing here?

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}
/* END CSS Clear */

body {

    font-size: 13px;
    background: #f3f3f3;

}

/* Body and Window Definitions */
#pane { 
    width: 980px;
    padding: 10px 9px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border-left: 1px solid #cdcdcd; 
    border-right: 1px solid #cdcdcd; 
    background: #fff;
    min-height: 1080px;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: The margin that would collapse would be on an element inside the `#pane` element. Can you show the HTML and CSS for that?

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing