# "float: left" makes the <li> item ignore the <div> tag it is wrapped in, unless the re is a certain height in pixels

Tags: html, css, html-lists

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/brumbul/u24M7/)

It may be a trivial question, but I can't seem to find the answer. In the case you can see in JS Fiddle, when the < div > in which the < ul >'s are wrapped doesn't have a certain height specified, it ignores the div in general and moves the bottom < div > behind everything.

Can anyone explain why?

Here is the code:

```
<div style="width: 750px;  margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: silver; ">
<div class="divWidgetList">
    <ul class="WidgetList">
        <li><a href="#"><sup>One</sup></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><sup>Two</sup></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><sup>Three</sup></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="WidgetList">
        <li><a href="#"><sup>Four</sup></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><sup>Five</sup></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><sup>Six</sup></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="WidgetList">
        <li><a href="#"><sup>Seven</sup></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><sup>Eight</sup></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><sup>Nine</sup></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="background-color: yellow">-----Something-----</div>
```

And the CSS

```
        .divWidgetList {
        width: 740px;
        height: auto;
        clear: left;
        float: left;
    }
    .WidgetList,.WidgetList li{
        color: #373737;
        min-width: 240px;
        display: block;
        float:left;
        font-family:'segoe ui', 'century gothic', arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 22px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-weight: lighter;
        height: auto;
        width: 33.33%;
        line-height: 40px;
        list-style-image: none;
        list-style-position: outside;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .WidgetList li {
        padding-left:35px;
    }
    .WidgetList li a:link
    {
        color: #373737;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .WidgetList li a:visited
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #373737;
    }
    .WidgetList li a:hover
    {
        color: #f07c01;
    }
```

Comment: Floated elements have no layout size, so the parent doesn't get any size either since it fits itself to its contents.

Comment: Is the explanation really that simple.... Please post is as an answer so I can "approve it"...

Comment: you can use the [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you keep parents of floated elements from collapsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)

Comment: @MyHeadHurts It seems you are right... Just didn't find it before... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply `float` to an element it is no longer part of the regular flow layout. As such the parent, which by default sizes to fit to its children, doesn't have any height at all when all its children are floating.

Possible solutions:

1. Give the parent container a fixed height to accomodate its children.
2. Use `display:inline-block` to position the elements next to eachother instead of float.
3. Use an element with a `clear` rule to break to below all floating elements.
4. The 'float everything' method - a floating element *will* resize to its floating children. This is generally a bad solution since you'll end up floating *everything* as the name implies.