# What is the correct inline CSS to replace this HTML table?

Tags: css, wordpress, html-table, css-float

Apologies for the low quality of this question.  CSS and HTML are not my usual stomping ground.  I have reached the stage where I'm just going to ask: how the heck do I do this?

I'm working on a friend's site (Wordpress, self-hosted) setting up some new pages for her.  I don't want to change the theme's stylesheet, and creating child themes is beyond me, so I think I'm limited to inline CSS (correct me if I'm wrong - I'm also a Wordpress noob).

I currently have the following HTML table, which begins as follows:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top; padding-right: 20px;">
<h2 style="padding-top: 5px;">Swiss balls/eggs</h2>
<p>Large inflatable balls of varying sizes that provide support and/or an unstable base to add challenge and variety to your workout. For those with balance issues, inflatable eggs roll in one direction only for security.</p></td>
<td style="width: 160px;"><img alt="Swiss ball" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/eqpt-swissball-trans.png" /></td>
<td style="vertical-align: top;" rowspan="6"><img alt="Fitness equipment" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/equipment-vertical.jpg" /></td>
</tr>
```

...and then has 5 further repeating row elements such as this:

```
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: top;">
<h2 style="padding-top: 5px;">Pilates balls</h2>
<p>Smaller, soft inflatable balls of varying size that can add support, postural correction and resistance for many of the classic exercises.</p></td>
<td style="width: 160px;"><img alt="Small Pilates balls x 5" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/eqpt-smallpilatesballsx5-trans.png" /></td>
</tr>
```

This produces a 3 column by 6 row layout similar to this.

[image: Layout example]

I have spent the last few hours browsing forums and stackoverflow etc. (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)) attempting the various implementations of floating divs, but while I can get examples to work with small amounts of text and no images, as soon as I replace the placeholder text with my images and text, it all falls apart and the divs start appearing one after the other vertically.

Comment: Can you please post the css you already have? A jsFiddle would be useful.

Comment: Can we have the fiddle please?

Comment: I wouldn't use inline CSS as some divs are created on the fly and will not have the CSS assigned to them. Instead consider writing a custom stylesheet and ensure it supersedes the current one.

Comment: Why are you trying to replace the HTML table by anything? It seems like a pointless exercise – which is especially unsuitable for a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You can only truly replace a table with floated `divs` if the columns are fixed-width. If the widths are fixed though, replace the rows (`<tr>`) with wrapper divs, and the cells (`<td>`) with fixed-width floated divs.

First I'll show it with non-inline styling, for clarity:

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col1'>
    <!-- First column content here -->
  </div>
  <div class='col2'>
    <!-- Second column content here -->
  </div>
  <div class='col2'>
    <!-- Second column content here -->
  </div>
  <hr class='clear'>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.row {
  width: 600px;
}
.col1, .col2, .col3 {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  width: 300px;
}
.clear {
  border: none;
  clear: both;
}
```

**Note**: You can change the widths of the individual columns & the table with the `.col` widths and the `.row` width, respectively.

Then inlined:

```
<div class='row' style='width: 600px'>
  <div class='col1' style='float: left; min-height: 1px; width: 200px'>
    <!-- First column content here -->
  </div>
  <div class='col2' style='float: left; min-height: 1px; width: 200px'>
    <!-- Second column content here -->
  </div>
  <div class='col2' style='float: left; min-height: 1px; width: 200px'>
    <!-- Second column content here -->
  </div>
  <hr class='clear' style='border: none; clear: both'>
</div>
```