# how to space between posts

Tags: wordpress, post, space

anyone can help me out? here are my codes, I can't seem to get space between the posts, thank you.

I tried to add padding and margin bottom to post-stuff as it would work, still didnt, help
[My blog](http://endingunplanned.com)

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;}

html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body,td,th {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #333333;
margini:0;
padding:0;
text-align:center; /* hack para o IE */
}

#all {
    width: 1000px;
margin:0 auto;         
text-align:left; /* "remédio" para o hack do IE */


}

a:link {
    color: #111111;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #111111;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FF9999;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #111111;
}

.menusize {
    background-color: #http://twitter.com/ ;
    width: 1000px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
    #menu ul {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    background-color:#ff9999;
    list-style:none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    #menu ul li { display: inline; }

    #menu ul li a {
    padding: 2px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* visual do link */
    background-color:#ff9999;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

.post {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    width: 690px;
margin-bottom:50px;
}

.date {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    background:#fff url('date.png') no-repeat scroll top left;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
}
.date .date-month {
    height:18px;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.date .date-day {
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:18px;
}

.title {
font-family: 'Vibur', cursive;
font-size: 30px;
}
.post {
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.tag {font: 12px/20px Arial; color:#333333; text-transform: uppercase; padding: 5px 0 0 0; height: 20px; overflow: hidden; -moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;}
.tag a {color:#FFFFFF; background:#ff9999; padding: 3px 5px 3px;-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;}
.tag a:hover {color:#FFFFFF; background:#88cfd5; -moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;}

.sidebar {
    clear: right;
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
margin-bottom:50px;

}

.footer {
    background-color: #88CFD5;
    clear: both;
    float: none;
position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
margin-top:10px;

}

.post-stuff {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333333;
}

.profile img {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
}
```

and the wordpress index file

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>        
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="post">
    <div class="info1">
      <div class="date"><div class="date"><br />

    <div class="date-month"><?php the_time('M'); ?></div>
    <div class="date-day"><?php the_time('d'); ?></div>
</div></div>
      <div class="title">     <div align="center"><?php the_title(); ?> <br />
    </div></div>
    </div>


    <div class="post-content"><?php the_content('Continue lendo &raquo;'); ?> </div>
<div class="post-stuff"><div align="center"><div class="tag"> posted in:  <?php the_tags('', ', '); ?> - <?php comments_popup_link(__('0 Comments'), __('1 Comment'), __('% Comments'),'Commentslink', __('Comments are closed')); ?> </div></div> 
  <?php endwhile; ?><?php else : ?><?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

first, there is a typo: margini, remove the i.

here now my suggestion for your index file. This will render the divs properly:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="post">
    <div class="info1">
        <div class="date"><br />
            <div class="date-month"><?php the_time('M'); ?></div>
            <div class="date-day"><?php the_time('d'); ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title">
        <div align="center"><?php the_title(); ?> <br /></div>
    </div>

    <div class="post-content"><?php the_content('Continue lendo &raquo;'); ?></div>
    <div class="post-stuff">
        <div align="center">
            <div class="tag"> posted in:  <?php the_tags('', ', '); ?> - <?php comments_popup_link(__('0 Comments'), __('1 Comment'), __('% Comments'),'Commentslink', __('Comments are closed')); ?> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: After building your example, which has the correct margin on Safari (MacOS), i think you might have a "collapsing div" issue on IE?
[read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)

Comment: I added the I cause I was trying to play with the footer, ended giving up through. about the date I wanted it ronded thats why I made it this way. 
I'm thinking starting it all over

Comment: I tried chrome and firefox, on firefox I made it work out but in chrome nothing can do.

Comment: I think as a first start, remove the second div of class date. In the DOM-Tree i can see that the second post is nested into the first. This is not what you want.

Unfortunately my reputation does not allow me to post pictures yet. So i cannot show it visually.

Comment: tried it, made my post go to my post title. had to get it back to place