# How to resize a div element automatically so that the content fits

Tags: c#, css, html

I need to do a lot of divs inside other divs, and I can't seem to understand what is the problem with my code, so the divs do not get the height of the divs below the- and everything is a mess!

my aspx code:

```
<div class="tabcontent">
    <div class="tabcontent-inner">
        <div class="tabcontent-inner-left grid_20">

        </div>

        <div class="tabcontent-inner-right grid_20">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my stylesheet css:

```
.tabcontent-inner {
    width: inherit;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.tabcontent-inner-left {
    padding: 20px 20px;
    border-left: solid 1px #ddd;
    width: 45%;
   float: left
}
.tabcontent-inner-right{
    padding: 20px 20px;
    border-right: solid 1px #ddd;
    width: 45%;
    float: right
}
```

Basically, I want the tabcontent-inner div to get the height of what is inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because on parent .tabcontent-inner you need to put overflow:auto property so that it will cover ups its children's height

you can find more suitable answer here [How do you keep parents of floated elements from collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)

Comment: setting `position:absolute;` to `.tabcontent-inner` would work too, but it has more consecuences than `overflow:auto;` or `overflow:hidden;` I would go for one of this

Comment: thank u!! thank u!! i have spent almost a day on it!

Comment: No Probs Good luck! Please note that there are other ways as well that you should know 1) applying float property right or left and width 100% 2) clearfix etc and you should apply them in the best way as per situation :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to Your CSS

```
.clearfix:after {
 content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
visibility: hidden;
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: both;
}
```

and

change

```
<div class="tabcontent-inner">
```

to

```
<div class="tabcontent-inner clearfix">
```

Semi colons are missing in the css after

```
float : left
```

and

```
float : right
```