# Why is the last line falling out of the wrapper?

Tags: css

My Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/7j5d9bcy/

My main problem is this code:

CSS:

```
 .picWrapper {
     width:250px;
     border: 1px solid black;
 }
 .picThumb {
     width:250;
     height:250;
     margin:auto;
     padding-bottom:10PX;
     text-align: center;
 }
 .picRating {
     width:250;
     height:90;
     text-align: center;
     padding-bottom:10px;
 }
 .picFilename {
     width:230;
     height:90;
     margin: auto;
     text-align: center;
     padding-bottom:5px;
 }
 .picBottomButtons {
     width:83px;
     float:left;
     text-align: center;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="picWrapper">
    <div class="picThumb">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" />
    </div>
    <div class="picRating">Rate this picture: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7</div>
    <div class="picFilename">abcd.jpg</div>
    <div class="picBottomButtons">1</div>
    <div class="picBottomButtons">2</div>
    <div class="picBottomButtons">3</div>
</div>
```

for some reason the last three DIVs (with the class picBottomButtons) is shown *outside* of the wrapper.
I am a noob to CSS3, can someone explain why bottom line does not sit in the wrapper please?

Comment: Because you've floated the elements. Floating means absolute positioning, meaning the elements are removed from the normal DOM flow. Either use one of the inline display properties or Google _"clearfix"_.

Comment: Like I said, I am a noob... could you explain that a bit more clearly please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7j5d9bcy/1/ -- float needs a clear. Look up clearfix too. Learn about floats. And use a value, not 250 but 250px

Comment: Look up basic css, terms, use, etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you keep parents of floated elements from collapsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ianhazzard/7j5d9bcy/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of floating `.picBottomButtons` elements, just use [**clearfix**](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/):

```
.picWrapper:before, 
.picWrapper:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.picWrapper:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7j5d9bcy/7/)

You can also add `overflow: auto;` to `.picWrapper`, more info how to [clear floats with overflow](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-clearing-floats-with-overflow).

[Understanding CSS Floats](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/understanding-css-floats/)

Comment: Thanks guys! Will vote all up but since this is the solution I used on my page, will chose this. Thanks for the links as well!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using a float for those bottom buttons, but nothing else is floating. Basically you have things playing by different rules. Remove the float and add `display: inline-block` and you should be good. You will probably need to adjust the width as well.

Updated Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/7j5d9bcy/4/

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Nit - Ha. Or a specific solution.

Comment: I down-voted you because this is a low quality answer that others with a similar problem are unlikely to gain much from. See the thread I marked the original question as a duplicate of for an example of a good answer. Don't take it personally.

Answer (score 1):

I would use display: inline-block rather than floating the images.  As stated above, floating removes the elements from the DOM.  It doesn't absolutely position them as stated, but it does take them out of the flow.

I've updated your JS Fiddle to be the following:

**CSS:**

```
.picBottomButtons{
    width:50px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I changed the width of the images so when inline they all fit horizontally.  I also changed the float:left to display: inline-block.

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/7j5d9bcy/5/