# Change DIV height to fit image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a DIV that's pretty much a box with a border that has a left-aligned image and text that's to the right of the image. Here's how I have it set up:

```html
    <div style="padding:1%; border-style:solid; border-size:1px; width:100%;">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/FwgZFNn.jpg" style="float:left; max-width:30%; max-height:200px;" />
        Here is some text.
    </div>
```

The problem is that, if the image is taller than the text, the surrounding DIV (and therefore the border) sizes itself to become the height it needs to be to fit in all the text, but the image overflows out of the DIV.

How can I make the DIV change its height to fit whichever is taller (the image or the text) so that both fit within the border?

Thanks.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle with the problem? css/html

Comment: The problem is that the img element in that div is floated. This link should be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing

Comment: You are trying to clear a float.  I would search for that term in google.  There are several solutions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block"` to your div.

```html
<div style="padding:1%; border-style:solid; border-size:1px; width:100%;display: inline-block">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/FwgZFNn.jpg" style="float:left; max-width:30%; max-height:200px;" />
    Here is some text.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @mikelt21 ! It generates a block element box that flows with surrounding content.

Answer (score 4):

add one property to div

```
overflow: hidden;
```

absolutely it will work .

Answer (score 2):

Add some element with `clear: both;` to "reserve" space for floated elements:

```html
<div style="padding:1%; border-style:solid; border-size:1px; width:100%;">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/FwgZFNn.jpg" style="float:left; max-width:30%; max-height:200px;" />
    Here is some text.

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: There are ways to do this without including an empty div. Have fun maintaining a project that has dozens of empty divs with inline styles.

Comment: @SteveSanders Yes, there is. Like self-clearing div. But this one is simpler to understand and to use as beginning point

Answer (score 1):

I would use `clearfix`, you can learn more about it [**here**](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)

Plus, careful, there is no `border-size` attribute, what you were trying to do was `border-width`.

Just my opinion here, it is best practices **not using inline styles**.

This way you have a clean solution.

So please see snippet below:

```css
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both
}
div {
  padding: 1%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
}
div > img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 30%;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/FwgZFNn.jpg" />Here is some text.
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't using inline styles, but there's a lot of other CSS I'm working with, so I thought posting all that would be TMI; so I just took the relevant parts and put them as inline styles.

Comment: btw by using clearfix you can apply that class to all of the containers you may have on your project with these kind of issues, without needing to create extra html.

Answer (score 1):

Just before the end of the div i.e before `</div>`, you need to clear the float. The error is due to float style of the image. To clear the float just add this

```
<span style="clear:both;"></span>
```

Just before the `</div>` tag.