# image grid flow outside the contentwrap

Tags: css

I'm creating an image grid. it works fine outside contentwrap but when in contenwrap all the images flow outside the contentwrap. whats wrong with my code? I'm facing one more problem is image caption.  I'm unable to add caption to images.

```
#contentwrap {
    width: 850px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#content {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    margin: 5px;
}

ul#grid {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0 0;
  width: 550px;  
  }

#grid li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 10px 5px;
  } 

.portfolio {
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;  margin-top:0;
  width: 513px;
  font-family: arial, serif; 
  text-align: center;
  }

#grid li a:hover img {
  opacity:0.3;  filter:alpha(opacity=30);
  }

#grid li img {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 7px; margin: 0;
  border: 1px dotted #58595b;
  width: 120px;
  height: 98px;
  }  
#grid li a {
  display: block;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="contentwrap">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="portfolio">
        <ul id="grid">
           <li><a href="newgrid.html"><img src="image.jpg"></a></li>
           <li><a href="newgrid.html"><img src="image.jpg"></a></li>
           <li><a href="newgrid.html"><img src="image.jpg"></a></li>   
        </ul>                                    
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you clearing your `float`s?

Comment: I want my image grid to be in center of a div.

Comment: That's fine. But, how are you clearing your `float`s?

Comment: Give us a working example of your code.

Comment: Ok i will give u jsfiddle link of my code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you keep parents of floated elements from collapsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)

Answer (score 0):

Here is working

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d87aq7yu/3/)

### simple add

```
 height:auto;
overflow:auto;
```

**to** `class = MyBox`