# Search area not appearing in a row

Tags: css

I am trying to make [this](http://www.amp.com.pk/) search area appear in row with the menu but I am unable to achieve it. Please guide me. Thanks.

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

Comment: can you make jsfiddle or paste code

Comment: Please post your markup. you'd think with 3000+ rep you'd know how to ask a good question by now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#branding #searchform {
clear: left;
margin-top: -31px;
}
```

try this it will work

Answer (score 0):

try taking your "searchform" out of your "header-wrapper" div

Comment: try to move it below the hr

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your div class main-menu-container-menu is collapsed. This container is unecessary in my view, but if you want to keep it, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)  problem. A good solution is the famous "[clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)".

Let us know the result and we can gide you from there. But make sure you perform this first step.

I suppose you will have to change the display:block by display:inline-block, for this same div.