# Why is my Footer is not Staying at Bottom of Page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer

For some odd reason my footer is showing up behind the content on my page, is not the right height anymore and I cannot seem to fix it. I have tried other answers and none of them work.  This can be viewed [here.](http://www.franhaines.co.uk/paddlethewye/?page_id=15) Does anyone have any ideas?

```css
.reviewwidget {
 width: 45%;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 float: left;
}

.reviews {
 width: 55%;
 float:right;
}

.single-review {
 position: relative;
 width:55%;
 float:right;
}

.quotation {
   position: relative; 
   width: 50px; 
   z-index:500;
}

.quotationend {
   position: relative; 
   float:right;
   width: 50px; 
   z-index:400;
   margin-top:-10px;
}

.single-review p {
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 550;
  margin-top: -20px;
  font-size:16px;
  font-style: italic;
}

Footer {
    background-color: #0b1b23;
 color: #ececec;
 padding: 5%;
 font-family: centrale_sans_regularregular, helvetica;
 position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your container as follows:

```
#container {   display: table-cell; }
```

This way it won't interfere with your footer placement.

Comment: Those of you who have downvoted this answer, care to explain what's wrong with my solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your `#container` element has floated content, which isn't cleared, causing `#container`'s height to collapse. You should read up on floating and clearfix, but here are two solutions [from this thread](http://[this%20thread%20has%20a%20number%20of%20clearfix%20solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)):

Reusable clearfix class to add to the `#container` element (recommended):

```
.clearfix:after { 
   content: " ";
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}
```

Quick and dirty:

```
#container { overflow: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the floated elements. You have to put a clearfix block in your html code before footer element or add pseudo element with clearfix styles, like iqnivek said.

Answer (score 0):

Its not that your footer is not staying on the bottom of your page.
your class "single-review" has the property of float-right and it hovering over the footer (causing it to autoscale height).

try removing float right from .single-review and that will fix your footer.

But you will need to put your page content into a wrapper to keep your elements in place or everything will continue to pull out and overlap