# Putting 2 divs next to each other with same class

Tags: php, html, css, web

I have 2 divs which i cannot give different class names, due to them being the same but in a repeatable php code, which doesen't allow me to give them different class names.
So i basically want to display them side by side.
I have tried giving them a float left and relative position and a master div surrounding them with absolute position and other things like that, but to no avail.

HTML:

```
<div class="master"> 
<div class="second">1st</div>
<div class="second">2nd</div>
</div>
```

CSS currently applied:

```
.second{
    color:#FFF;
    width:300px;
    height: 10%;
    background-color:#69F;
    border-radius:25px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    float:left;
}
.master{
width:960px;
padding-top:12%;
margin: 0 auto;
font-size:50px;
}
```

Comment: `float: left` should work.

Comment: Simply using float left is not working for some reason. Do you want me to display all the CSS currently being applied on them?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hnx82xgr/1/ - working i think.

Comment: Yes, but for some reason, not on my page :(

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: Chrome
Here are the 2 files
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/72958ac2fbd7d42179c6

Comment: @Jay Moy I can't. As you see on my github, the divs are both the same, except it is repeated on a while inside the php. I can't give it separate names or do any individual work on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="master"> 
<div class="second" style="float:left">1st</div>
<div class="second">2nd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't give the inside divs specific styles, whatever is being applied to one, also goes to the other.

Comment: I think your code itself working see jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cashwanikumar/7nd7dmkt/   This is what you want?

Comment: try to put   float : left !important; see if it work

Comment: It has float left @Ashwani. But insn't working. For some reason unknown to me.

Comment: i mean put  !important also

Answer (score 2):

Add this `css` -

```
.second {

    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;

}
```

Check the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hnx82xgr/)

Answer (score 0):

In your css code put this:

```
.class
{
float:left;
}
```

also make sure that if you put the width of that class `.second`  then it should not exceed 50% as these two divs are only contained in the main div with the class `.master`

Comment: Their sizes aren't exceeding 50%. But the float left isn't working

Comment: use float:left at the top in the .second class declaration and use `display:block` after that

Comment: i ran your code in the question and it works fine in my screen divs are exactly beside each other

Comment: For some reason on my page it isn't working. Might be some conflict with other CSS or something :( I posted on a reply my full page code and CSS

Answer (score 0):

If you use "float:left" you have to set a width (in percentage -obviously they must not exceed 100%-, or pixels) for the floated divs. Also, you might want to use this css for the container:

```
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

More on this:

[How do you keep parents of floated elements from collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display: inline-block`

```
.second {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and make sure not to increase the width of any `.second` container to more than half of the parent