# Unexpected margin / padding while dragging (jQuery Ui)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm implementing a draggle unordered list through jQuery ui and am expecting issues where while element is dragged It has some sort of margin or padding added to it that I can't find.

```
<ul class="sortable-queue">
                            <li class="item-dragable">
                                Drag me
                            </li>
                            <li class="item-dragable">
                                Drag me
                            </li>
                            <li class="item-dragable">
                                Drag me
                            </li>
                        </ul>

 ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .item-dragable {
        width: 108px;
        background-color: @color-white;
        height: 150px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        margin-right: 11px;
        .drop-shadow(2px, 2px, 3px, 0.1);

        &:last-child {
            margin-right: 0 !important;
        }

        &:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
```

(Less used for css, and ul refers to `.sortable-queue`)

This is how list looks initially:

[image]

and this is how it looks when item is dragged (I want to only drag it horizontally)

[image]

initiating jQuery ui:

```
$( ".sortable-queue" ).sortable({
      revert: true,
      axis: "x",
      containment: "parent", 
      scroll: false
    });
```

Comment: Did you use $( ".item-dragable" ).draggable({ containment: "parent", scroll: false }); as from example of [constrain-movement](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement)?

Comment: @fuyushimoya just updated question to show how I initiate it at the moment (added your parameters) still no change :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to add `float:left` to your `draggable`'s css, after adding it, it'll work, however, the ul's height will now unable to calculate, so from [How do you keep parents of floated elements from collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)

Add

```
ul:after { 
   content: " ";
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}
```

will make the children's height visible to `ul`

Here's what you might expect : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrnrgv9L/1/)