# Put login form to the right of the page

Tags: jquery, forms, css, jquery-mobile, authentication

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/h7gxpqn0/42/). Despite the fact that I am applying this rule

```
#login {
    float: right;
}
```

the form will stay next to Leaderboard link. In a mobile, this is not a problem, since everything will be displayed in a one column fahsion, but in a desktop I would like the logo to be to leftmost position, the textbox and Leaderboard to be somewhere in the center and the login to the rightmost position.

What am I missing?

---

Notice that with the actual logo everything is fine (with regards to the logo), so ignore the ugly effect the linked logo has in the example.

Comment: Are you using jquery-mobile ?

Comment: Yes @Zl3n, you can see it in the example too.

Comment: It is very strange indeed.

Comment: @Zl3n yes, that's why I posted. Maybe there is something from jquery-mobile that get things complicated. Even `!important` keyword won't help. :/

Comment: Would this work for you ? - http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/h7gxpqn0/42/

Comment: @Zl3n it's something, but I think it does not go all the way along the right end of the screen. Also, I can not see which is the new code in your fiddle. Maybe an upvote to the question would help to bring more people here to help!

Comment: @Yogita088 what u commented is the same with my link. Probably you forgot to update!

Comment: @gsamaras oops... here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/h7gxpqn0/44/

Comment: If you choose the absolute position , we must do everything in absolute ...

Comment: @Yogita088 ZI3n is right. This will solve the problem in first sight, but when for example you go into the mobile screen it won't be aligned with the other 3 elements of the header.

Comment: @gsamaras sorry, don't understand why anything isn't working

Comment: @Zl3n you did your try. Also the answer you almost gave helped me re-think somethings, but still I am not able to find a solution. You have upvoted the question though, so hopefully, this will attract humans.. :)

Comment: @gsamaras the best solution I can do, css changed at bottom, but position absolute is a problem http://jsfiddle.net/zlen/h7gxpqn0/45/

Comment: @Zl3n thanks for another good effort. Yes, because when you resize the screen to fit a mobile's one, everything get overlapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display flex is applied to parent element (`ui-block-solo`). It would be better not to use display flex, float alignment and position absolute at the same time.

If you choose to keep display flex, you can use flex alignment - you can read more here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

If there is float alignment and position absolute, position absolute will be applied. Furthermore if you prefer float alignment or position absolute you should use media queries for mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `display: flex` in the parent div `.ui-block-solo`. Float has no effect on flex items.

Comment: You only need to remove the display: flex property.

Comment: I tried this, but things overflow from the layer of the header.

Comment: It is because you are floating elements inside a non-floated parent. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing

Answer (score 0):

Try using the grid system of Bootstrap in order to position your elements. 
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

For example you can have something like this:
http://www.codeply.com/go/UVfJSRytc2

FYI Bootstrap's grid system is really easy to use and it saves you a lot of time from working with plain CSS. With the grid you actually split the screen in rows and columns and you can easily place your elements anywhere you want. I suggest you take a look at it for future reference :)

Comment: Could you show how to apply the instructions in the link in my specific problem?