# Logo is falling of header in Mozilla

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, css-position

This is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/h7gxpqn0/42/), which I have taken from my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475724/put-login-form-to-the-right-of-the-page).

The CSS is:

```
#logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;  
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .ui-block-solo { flex-direction: column; }
    #logo { position: static; }
}
```

Now see how it looks in Chrome:
[image]
Now see how it looks in Mozilla:
[image]

See how the logo falls goes out of the header? How to fix this?

Mozilla version: *40.0.3*. However, one of my users spotted the issue, but I do not know the version of his Mozilla.

Comment: Let's start with the FF version #?

Comment: Good idea @DavidZ.Lerner, updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be as concise and technical of an answer as you'd like, but this is undoubtedly caused in differences between Chrome & Firefox' rendering engines.

If you're looking for a quick fix, I'd recommend setting `#logo { top: 0; }`. This seems to solve the problem in FF without compromising its appearance in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

It's all due to the `position: flex;` on the parent of `#logo`, which is rendered differently in almost every browser. That, and the fact that you do not have any rules regarding the vertical positioning of `#logo`.

If, for example, you add

```
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

to your `#logo`, most browsers will center it vertically inside the first parent with `position: relative`.

Comment: I'd stick with Andrei's answer, too, as it's unlikely you really wanted the #logo to be absolutely positioned on top. However, that said, setting top in general is your way to go

Comment: I decided to accept David's answer, despite his honesty, because in a mobile, the logo gets cut off with Andrei's solution on the top, while with David's it's perfect.

Comment: In the fiddle you posted I see your `#logo` is positioned `static` on narrow devices. So basically, my solution doesn't even apply. You just have to add `margin-top: 10px` in the `@media (max-width: 500px) {#logo{}}`. I personally never use `position: static`, but that's just me.

Comment: Anyway, basically both solutions fix the same thing (your code was lacking): the vertical positioning. They are both technically correct.