# Bootstrap column overlapping another at medium width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't understand why my bootstrap columns are overlapping here. I've created a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/bnzTYEnkAv), to illustrate the issue I tried adding a cleafix div directly after the `col-xs-12` div to see if it would fix the issue and it sort of did, but it forced the left hand sidebar to move beneath the right hand one.

This issue is only at what appears to be medium screen widths and don't know why this is happening. I know it has to do with using hidden-xs and the col-xs-12, but don't understand why.

Comment: There is no overlap in Firefox 41.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 hidden-xs">
    <div style="background-color:orange;">
      <h3>A random title</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
    <div style="background-color:blue;">
      <h1>Some Random Title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 hidden-xs">
    <div style="background-color:red;">
      <h4>DFSDSDF</h4>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

> This is an issue related to [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing). The parent doesn't gets the
>   height of floated child.

For your issue, simply declare `col-classes` for other viewport as well as shown above, because, they prevent such issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the screen to which you're resizing doesn't fit into -md- anymore. Try changing it to `col-md-2 hidden-xs col-xs-2`, that is, add `col-xs-2` to the first and third div. And you'll observe there's no overlapping of columns.