# CSS Floats does not seem to work in header

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am working on a header that contain a brand logo and a navigation. The header itself is contained in a div named container. The markup is like -

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="head">
        <div class="brand>Brand Name</div>
        <div class="nav'>Nav content Here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS I am using is like

```
.container{
    width:100%;
    margin:10% auto;
}
.head{
    float:left;
    width:100%
}
.brand{
    float:left;
    margin:0 3%;
    width:auto;
}
.nav{
    float:right;
    margin:0 3%;
    width:auto
}
```

The Problem is that the all the content flows out of the Main `container <div>`and the container takes a height of 0px. The content is displaying as i want it to be but the main container is taking a height of 0px.

I want to display the brand logo and the navigation side by side. It would be great if you could make a fiddle with the code. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Sorry for not researching before posting the question. The Clearfix hack is a life saver but there were several different ways also. Listed here - [How do you keep parents of floated elements from collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use clearfix hack explained [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

html:

```
<div class="container clearfix">
<div class="head">
    <div class="brand">Brand Name</div>
    <div class="nav">Nav content Here</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container{
    width:100%;
    margin:10% auto;
}
.head{
    float:left;
    width:100%
}
.brand{
    float:left;
    margin:0 3%;
    width:auto;
}
.nav{
    float:right;
    margin:0 3%;
    width:auto
}
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/siffer/2uoapy81/1/)

Comment: Thank You. It saved me a lot of headache

Answer (score 0):

You have to use clearfix for .container div like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j4jofcpj/)** to automatically clear its child elements, which have float.

```
<div class="container clearfix">
  <div class="head">
    <div class="brand">Brand Name</div>
    <div class="nav">Nav content Here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here corrected HTML syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

**You got `html` issue:**

```
<div class="brand>Brand Name</div>
```

**and:**

```
<div class="nav'>Nav content Here</div>
```

I fixed these and it wokring fine! without changing your `css

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="head">
        <div class="brand">Brand Name</div>
        <div class="nav">Nav content Here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4cduk9u6/)**

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     <div class="brand>Brand Name</div>
>     <div class="nav'>Nav content Here</div>
> ```

change to

```
<div class="brand">Brand Name</div>
<div class="nav">Nav content Here</div>
```