# Make div resize automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got div

```
     <div class="PF">  
                  <img src="img" class="FollowerPic">
                  <span>Name</span>
                  <div class="Text"></div>
                <div class="readURL">
                  <img src="../img/x.png"  class="closeP">
                  <img src="" class="readIMG"></div>
               </div>
    </div>
```

Now div with class "Text" and image with class "readIMG" are defined by user they can be 100px or 500 px height.

```
.PF{
    width: 600;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 500;
    span{
        position: absolute;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 32;
        margin-left: 140;
        margin-top: 50;
    }
}

.readURL{
    margin-left: -19;
    margin-top: 100;
    width: 300;
    height: 260;
    position:absolute;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    display: none;  
    .readIMG{
        width:600px;
        // position:@Abs;
        margin:-55 19 100;
        height: inherit;
    }
    .closeP{
        position:@Abs;
        width: 40;
        margin-left: 180%;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
}
```

I have tried this code to the parent div but it does not want to resize it stays the same height

Comment: Also if you add a unit to 500. The property "min-height" of 500 on the parent means that the parent div will always be at least 500 in size. Perhaps you meant "max-height"?

Comment: @papakia No.When i delete min-height it's height is 0

Comment: Then your div maybe collapsing, I suggest posting the rest of your CSS for the surrounding elements that could influence your div of class PF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing

Comment: @papakia I added span's style

Comment: if the span does not need to be absolute positioned then remove `position:absolute` from the span and remove the `min-height` property from it's parent, it should fix the issue

Comment: @papakia Yes now it resizes when i change "Text" but not image

Comment: what are the css properties and values applied to the classes `FollowerPic`, `closeP ` and `readIMG`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
.PF{
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
.PF span {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    }
```

It is good practice to use measurement units for your css properties or browsers will render the elements with default measurement values:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_measurement_units.htm

Comment: Yes now it resizes when i change "Text" but not image

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the units.

For example:

```
.PF{
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about "px" for height and width

```
  https: //plnkr.co/edit/qr1gUaeeWeLARIVDPg5B?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would want the divs to auto resize this would mean you want the screen to fit screen resize or even fit on different screens 
.
Try to apply Percentages and media queries in order to work out

i.e.

```
.PF{
    min-width:100px;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 500px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And to make the images follow suit you may apply percentages onto the also

i.e.

```
 <div class="PF">  
              <img src="img" style="width:100%;" class="FollowerPic">
              <span>Name</span>
              <div class="Text">....
```

Alternatively:
if you set height to 100%; it looks at the parents height. One way to do this is not even giving the child a height of 100% but  I could also suggest You give the parent a style of relative position and the child an absolute position. then force it to fit the parent. i.e.

```html
<style>
.parent
{
 height:100%; 
 min-height:500px; 
 position:relative;  
 display:block; 
 border:#093 solid 1px;  
}

.PF
{
 background-color:#999; 
 border:#939 solid 1px; 
 height:100%; 
 bottom:0; 
 position:absolute; 
 bottom:0; 
 top:0; 
 left:0; 
 right:0; 
 display:block;
}

</style>


<!--The parent-->
<div class="parent">

<!--The child-->
    <div class="PF">
                  <img src="img" class="FollowerPic">
                  <span>Name</span>
                  <div class="Text"></div>
                  <div class="readURL">
                  <img src="../img/x.png"  class="closeP">
                  <img src="" class="readIMG"></div>
                  </div>
 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so is height auto or 100%?

Comment: @MuradEmi Me i would prefer positioning to force it if height does not work