# Divs are overlayed instead of stacked on top of another

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, `.instructions` and `.personal_info`, that I want stacked on top of another. `.personal_info` has top and bottom borders. The two divs seem to be overlaid on top of one another, which is not what I want. I want `.instructions` to remain where it is, but I want `.personal_info` to appear below it.

Please let me know what I'm missing here. My code is below:

```css
.instructions {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.column-left {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.column-right {
  float: right;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 25px 10px 0px 10px;
}
.column-center {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 25px 10px 0px 10px;
}
.personal_info {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="instructions">
  <div class="column-left"></div>
  <div class="column-center"></div>
  <div class="column-right"></div>
</div>

<div class="personal_info">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you keep parents of floated elements from collapsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)

Comment: Did the answers help?

Answer (score 0):

Better to use CSS display:flex
Code

```
<div style="display:flex;">
    <div style="width:33%; background-color:wheat;">Left</div>
    <div style="width:33%;">Center</div>
    <div style="width:33%; background-color:snow">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mistake: <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column;">

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the floated elements, just use `overflow: hidden` on `.instructions`:

```css
.instructions {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.column-left {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.column-right {
  float: right;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 25px 10px 0px 10px;
}
.column-center {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 25px 10px 0px 10px;
}
.personal_info {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="instructions">
  <div class="column-left"></div>
  <div class="column-center"></div>
  <div class="column-right"></div>
</div>

<div class="personal_info">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

More about clearing floats can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/), and [here](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here
[Possible Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/michaelrodov/Lf1hLb2b/)

```
.instructions {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.column-left {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
.column-right {
  float: right;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 25px 10px 0px 10px;
}
.column-center {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 25px 10px 0px 10px;
}
.personal_info {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

It's not really clear whats the whole picture but for the excersize above you can do few things:

1. position personal_info before instructions so it would be drawn first and set position:absolute to instructions

   2. set personal_info to be position:absolute, top:0, z-index:-1
      this will remove the personal_info from normal html generation flow and will position it right below to it's sibling .instructions
      Giving it z-index will make sure it stays below (if it's zindex is lower then instructions)

I'd also advice you to start using "display: flex" for positioning of "columns"

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `display: flex;` to your `instructions` class.

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp), the flex value:

> Displays an element as an block-level flex container.

While not entirely related to your issue, you can learn more about how floats can affect block-level elements from this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/what-does-the-css-rule-clear-both-do#answer-12871734)