# Image gallery not working properly

Tags: html, css

```
<section>
  <style>
    div.img {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    div.img:hover {
      border: 1px solid #777;
    }

    div.img img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }

    div.desc {
      padding: 15px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .responsive {
      padding: 0 6px;
      float: left;
      width: 24.99999%;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
      .responsive {
        width: 49.99999%;
        margin: 6px 0;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      .responsive {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }

    .clearfix:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
  </style>

  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="img">
      <a target="_blank" href="img\aviary-image-1479454871589.jpeg">
        <img src="/img/aviary-image-1479454871589.jpeg" alt="A Boeing 747-400 descending" width="300" height="200">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">A Boeing 747-400 descending</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="img">
      <a target="_blank" href="img\Screenshot_2016-11-18-13-30-35-973.jpg">
        <img src="/img/Screenshot_2016-11-18-13-30-35-973.jpg" alt="Boeing 787-9 touching down" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Boeing 787-9 touching down</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="img">
      <a target="_blank" href="img\Slack for iOS Upload.jpg">
        <img src="/img/Slack for iOS Upload.jpg" alt="Boeing 777-200ER climbing" width="600" height="400">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">A Boeing 777-200ER climbing</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Please note, that this is only a section of the page, that is why there are no starting tags etc.**

For some reason, my gallery is not loading. The images are uploaded, but none of the gallery is showing up on the site. You can look at the site here: https://britishairways.000webhostapp.com/photos.html

Anything I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: But I put one before and after the CSS properties?

Comment: add `overflow: hidden` to the container that holds your `.responsive` div-s - it's collapsed to `0` height now

Comment: the `<footer>` overlaps your gallery. A shortest way to resolve it is to remove `position: relative;` off its css at line 761 of https://britishairways.000webhostapp.com/css/styles.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `<section>` in which your gallery items are located a flex container. Just like:

```
section {
  display: flex;
}
```

Visual Reference:

[image]

Comment: I have more than one section, can I apply this to only one section?

Comment: @GiacomoLawrance Yes! the section in which all the three image gallery items are present.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @GiacomoLawrance It's my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

The `section` holding the three gallery images has zero height. This, in turn, is because the gallery images have `float:left`, which takes them out of the layout flow and causes their parent not to use their size in calculating its height.

See [How do you keep parents of floated elements from collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)