# background-color of div does not appear in the image

Tags: html

I have used a p tag inside a div tag:

```
div{background-color:#3B3B3B;}

p{float:left;}
```

The `background-color` of div does not appear in the image:

[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: #language2{
 background-color: #3B3B3B;
 height: 300px;
}
<div id="language2">
    <p style="float:left;margin:0;padding:35px 20px;font-size: 20px;font-family:Righteous;color: #FFFFFF">English</p>
</div>

Comment: I can't figure out a problem by just giving me that. I need to see your HTML and CSS styles. Please update your question to include and format your code correctly.

Comment: I put the #language2 in <style>

Comment: I dont know how , this is the first time I've asked

Comment: If you post all of your code into a fiddle, I'll take a look

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the P programming language, please do not use the [tag:p] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using float on a child will cause the parent to collapse. There are many alternative solutions, see [How do you keep parents of floated elements from collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)

Comment: thank youuu, I solved it xD

Comment: [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/k1qayb3k/) a fiddle of the code as you describe it. The quickest fix you might want to try is move `float left` to the `div {}` selector.

Comment: ^^ I moved it and it works

Comment: You should be flagging questions as duplicates rather than posting links to other Stack Overflow posts as an answer.