# How to extend container around wrapped elements

Tags: html, css, layout

How do I extend the container around the wrapped elements so when I put in content it extends automatically?  The container is stuck at the top of the page above the header even though the header is wrapped in the container div.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>basic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div id="container">
       <div id="header">
           <div class="nav_left">
               <a href="#">Home</a>
               <a href="#">About</a>
               <a href="#">Download</a>
               <a href="#">Contact</a>

           </div>
       </div>
               <div id="bigbox">

               </div>


   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html{
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: grey;

}
#container{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
#header{
    width:80%;
}
.nav_left{
    float:left;
    height:30px;
}
#bigbox{
    width:80%;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you keep parents of floated elements from collapsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)

Comment: You always clear floats in the parent container of floated elements. I added a class you can apply to such parents in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the floats in your `#header` element. I have my trusty .clear-floats class:

```
.clear-floats {
  display: block;
}

.clear-floats:after
{
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
```

Add that to your stylesheet and then add `class="clear-floats"` to your header element.