# CSS positioning divs into content

Tags: html, css

Been doing little work on my site and currently, I'm having issues with positioning. I don't know why, but my `divs` seem to be out of the content for some reason. That's how it looks:

[image]

And the way its defined:

```
float: left;
font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
margin: 10px;
width: 100px; 
height: 100px;
background:#FFFFFFFF; 
text-align: center;
display: inline;
border: solid 2px #0047b3;
font-size: 28px;
```

The way content is defined:

```
#content { background-color:#6699ff; margin: 5px; border: 2px solid #0047b3; padding-left: 10px;}
```

I just want to get my created div into the content div, but somehow it doesn't work.

Comment: [MCVE] are very helpful for us to assist you here. We get more information with HTML. Make sure to edit changes into your question. Don't add them as answers or comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/what-methods-of-clearfix-can-i-use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of 'float: left'. Floating an element takes it "out of the flow" of the document. You might have better luck by removing the float property and making them 'display: inline block'.

Comment: i fixed some of my code, and added this display type you proposed and it worked perfectly, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you may add an extra `<div class="spacer"></div>` as the last child and use

```
.spacer {
    clear:both;
}
```

more info can be found here
[How do you keep parents of floated elements from collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing)