# css arrange two div block in different row

Tags: html, css

I am trying to arrange two div in different rows. They work fine until I add some float elements. Anybody could help me fix the issue? The second row cannot appear as a normal div block, I do not know how to fix this.

```css
<style>
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

h4 {
    float:left;
    
}
ul {
    float:right;
    
}
    
.first-block {
    
}    
    
.second-block {
    position:relative;
    
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="first-block">
    <h4>Left Top</h4>
    <ul><li>Right Top</li></ul>
</div>

<div class="second-block">
    <h4>Left Bottom</h4>
    <ul><li>Right Bottom</li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you inspect the element in your browser you can see what happens. Because you use float the size of the `h4` and `ul` wont stretch the parent div so they will both have a size of 0 and will go side by side.

Comment: Using float the element is removed from his normal flow. so the first and second block has width:0 and height:0. so first set .first-block{position:relative} and give to first and second block some dimension example width:100% and height:50px. Consider to use flexbox instead of float

Comment: Thanks to all heartwarming guys. I misunderstood the function `div` and think everything inside `div` will be separated in blocks. I will do as your guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to clear your floats, as parents of floated elements do collapse. Read about how to use **clearfix**. One of many methods is to use an `overflow: auto` here.

But for what you might want to achieve, you might be better off using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

div h4 {
  float: left;
}

div ul {
  float: right;
}

.block {
  overflow: auto;
}

.first-block {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
}

.second-block {
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="block first-block">
  <h4>Left Top</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>Right Top</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="block second-block">
  <h4>Left Bottom</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>Right Bottom</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/what-methods-of-clearfix-can-i-use

Comment: How do you keep parents of floated elements from collapsing?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing

Comment: What is a clearfix? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to clear float like this below

```
.second-block {
    position:relative;
    clear: both;
}
```

in this case using flex-box would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

When you use float, the size of the container for the floated elements wont stertch beacuse the float elements is removed from the normal flow. So if you give some dimension to the container it will work.

[Float documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

But consider to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

h4 {
    float:left;
    
}
ul {
    float:right;
}
    
.first-block {
    position:relative;
     width:100%;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}    
    
.second-block {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-block">
    <h4>Left Top</h4>
    <ul><li>Right Top</li></ul>
</div>

<div class="second-block">
    <h4>Left Bottom</h4>
    <ul><li>Right Bottom</li></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code snippet below. Use `clear: both` CSS property to align the div in different rows.

Hope this will help.

```css
<style>
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

h4 {
    float:left;
    
}
ul {
    float:right;
    
}
    
.first-block {
    
}    
    
.second-block {
    position:relative;
    clear: both;
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="first-block">
    <h4>Left Top</h4>
    <ul><li>Right Top</li></ul>
</div>

<div class="second-block">
    <h4>Left Bottom</h4>
    <ul><li>Right Bottom</li></ul>
</div>
```