# Background color in div element not showing

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm taking this course called HTML, CSS, and Javascript for Web Developers. I'm in the lecture that talks about floating elements, my problem is that when I add the properties "float" and "margin-right" to the element p selector, the background of the div disappears. Can somebody help me, please?

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
}

p {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#p1 {
  background-color: #A52A2A;
}

#p2 {
  background-color: #DEB887;
}

#p3 {
  background-color: #5F9EA0;
}

#p4 {
  background-color: #FF7F50;
}

section {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="p1"></p>
  <p id="p2"></p>
  <p id="p3"></p>
  <p id="p4"></p>
</div>
<section>This is regular content continuing after the paragraph boxes</section>
```

Comment: If you also float the div left, then you should see the result you're after

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you keep parents of floated elements from collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218760/how-do-you-keep-parents-of-floated-elements-from-collapsing) and [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/what-methods-of-clearfix-can-i-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `float` you need to clear it because it gets removed from the document flow. This process of clearing is also called **Clearfix**.

You can do something like this:

```
div:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
}

div:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

p {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#p1 {
  background-color: #A52A2A;
}

#p2 {
  background-color: #DEB887;
}

#p3 {
  background-color: #5F9EA0;
}

#p4 {
  background-color: #FF7F50;
}

section {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="p1"></p>
  <p id="p2"></p>
  <p id="p3"></p>
  <p id="p4"></p>
</div>
<section>This is regular content continuing after the paragraph boxes</section>
```

You should not use `floats` now. Use modern technologies like `flexbox` and `grid`.

Some useful resources:

- [How TO - Clear Floats (Clearfix)](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp)
- [The Clearfix: Force an Element To Self-Clear its Children](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)
- [Clearfix: A Lesson in Web Development Evolution](https://css-tricks.com/clearfix-a-lesson-in-web-development-evolution/)

Comment: Thank you so much!! It seemed to have solved the problem. And I'll check up the links, guess the course I'm taking is a bit outdated... You're so nice, thank you again :3

Comment: @Lunazul8 Its not important to read all those links . . .They are just for reference. . . can you share the URL of the course so I can check!

Comment: But the first link solved my problem, I added the property overflow: auto; to div and it worked :3... Here's the link of the course:  https://www.coursera.org/learn/html-css-javascript-for-web-developers/lecture/Tj19u/lecture-21-positioning-elements-by-floating

Comment: @Lunazul8 That's seems too old to me. . . You should prefer better once's,  do you want a premium course or a free one!

Comment: I can't afford a premium one so a free one is the better option for me

Comment: @Lunazul8 This is far better than that one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mU6anWqZJcc

Comment: Most people use VS Code now. . . it has a lot of features . . . and made by Microsoft . . . If you want help in setting up the editor let me know. . . You can download it from here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Download

Answer (score 0):

The `float` attribute remove element from the document flow. As the `div` that contains `p` floating elements and this not have a setted `height`, the height pass to 0. Set a height for the div.

Comment: When I set any height for the background, the content of the section element, gets on top of the background, dividing it :c

Answer (score 0):

The `float` properties acts like a `position:absolute` would

Even if the `<p>` is in the `<div>`, this property makes it "pop out" of the `<div>`, removing its automatic height and width, thus , making the `<div>` 0px height, and 0px witdh, in such a way you can't see it

A way to fix it is setting a height and witdh to your `<div>`

Comment: I tried that, but then the section element gets in between, dividing the backgound :c... Thank you anyway